# WCF is not sending stream (net.tcp binding)

Tags: c#, wcf, service, stream, net.tcp

I can not send stream using net.tcp binding. I have MessageContract to send data, and WCF is passing the FileName but the stream FileByteStream is empty

```
[MessageContract]
public class FileUploadMessage
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string Filename;
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream FileByteStream;
}
```

My service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISlaveService
{
    [OperationContract]
    FileUploadMessage SendPattern(FileUploadMessage image);
}
```

Service implementation (both sending and returning the stream are not working):

```
public FileUploadMessage SendPattern(FileUploadMessage image)
{
    try
    {
        ImageSource source = BitmapFrame.Create(image.FileByteStream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        MainWindow.Instance.imagePattern.Source = source;

        Stream imageStream2 = File.OpenRead(@"C:\aaa.jpg");
        image.FileByteStream = imageStream2;
        return image;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: add log
        return null;
    }
}
```

Starting the service:

```
public static void StartService()
{
    try
    {
        Uri tcpUrl = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:" + Config.Instance().LocalPort + "/SlaveService");

        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SlaveService), tcpUrl);

        NetTcpBinding tcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding();
        tcpbinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
        tcpbinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
        tcpbinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
        tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISlaveService), tcpbinding, "net.tcp://localhost:" + Config.Instance().LocalPort + "/SlaveService");

        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(),
        "net.tcp://localhost:" + Config.Instance().LocalPort + "/SlaveService/mex");

        host.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TO DO: Logger.Add("Failed to start Slave service. " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Client connection:

```
public bool Connect(string address)
{
    NetTcpBinding tcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding();
    tcpbinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
    tcpbinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
    tcpbinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
    tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
    tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
    tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
    tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;

    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://" + address + "/SlaveService");
    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISlaveService>(tcpbinding, endpoint);
    client = null;

    try
    {
        client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Add("Exception occured while trying to connect. " + e.Message);
        if (client != null)
        {
            ((ICommunicationObject)client).Abort();
        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I can send text and digits, but when I'm trying to send stream it is sending an empty stream. I red on forums that MaxReceivedMessageSize should be a solution, but it is not solving my problem.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

The contract should be:

```
    [OperationContract]
    FileUploadMessage SendPattern(Stream image);
```

Comment: I tried this, I added FileUploadMessage after using Stream. This code is working when I'm sending file as a byte array instead of stream. I don't know why